# Get instance of the class of a ClassFile

Tags: java, classloader, instantiation, .class-file

i've a folder which contains jar files. i load all of those files, then i load all of the class files which are in the jar files. now i want to make an instance of every class of the class files.

```
ClassFile[] classFiles = loadClassFiles();
Object[] objects = new Object[classFiles.length];
for(int i = 0; i < classFiles.length; i++){
 objects[i] = getNewInstanceOf(classfiles[i]);
}
```

This is what i ve so far. only the method `getNewInstaceOf(Classfile file)` is missed. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

If there is an easier way to load all classes from a jar file, you can also tell me. i don't have to get the classFiles or to load the jarfile, if there is any other way.

Also you might should know, that every Class does have a constructor without parameters
thanks for help :)

Comment: see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html

Comment: You should really read the docs before asking questions. The documentation really answers it. It's the same for your `Class.getResource` question.

Comment: @Scary Wombat i ve a ClassFile not a class. i dont know how to get the Class which is represented by the ClassFile. That's what i wanna know. How to make instances i already knew, but i don't know how to make it from ClassFiles

Comment: what package in ClassFile?

Comment: look. i made a jar file called testfile.jar wich has one package called testpackage which contains one class file clled testclass.class. i loaded the testclass.class into a com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.util.ClassPath.ClassFile object. now i want to create an instance of the class which is repressented by my testclass.class file which is loaded in the ClassFile object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the name of the class you want you could use

```
File file = getJarFileToLoadFrom();   
String lcStr = getNameOfClassToLoad();   
URL jarfile = new URL("jar", "","file:" + file.getAbsolutePath()+"!/");    
URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] {jarfile });   
Class loadedClass = cl.loadClass(lcStr);
```

Comment: gr8, that's what i'm searching for thank you! :D That's perfect :)

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but can you help me again please? what's the syntax of the classname? i always get a classnotfoundexception, because it can't find my class JavaPlugin.class in the package plugin (plugin.JavaPlugin.class is what i used as parameter)

Comment: try `plugin.JavaPlugin`